# What is Django's purpose in single page applications?

Tags: python, django, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm looking to create my next application using Django and AngularJS, but the role separation between each framework has me a little confused.

Am I correct in saying that Django would only be handling authentication and provide some sort of REST API (such as using Django API framework or tastypie) while AngularJS would pretty much handle everything else?

Comment: I would turn it otherwise. Angular would manage everything that is UI and django would do everything else (DB management, heavy processing, administration interface, interaction with other server/services, account management, ........). Basically, you just remove all the awkward django form/template management and replace it with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you are right: as a rule of thumb use django to create the backend application and let angular handle the views.

A nice guideline is given by the [django-angular project](http://django-angular.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).